# Finding the smallest integer that appears at least k times

Tags: java, integer, key, hashtable

You are given an array A of integers and an integer k. Implement an algorithm that determines, in linear time, the smallest integer that appears at least k times in A.

I have been struggling with this problem for awhile, coding in Java, I need to use a HashTable to find the smallest integer that appears at least k times, it also must be in linear time.

This is what I attempted but it does not pass any of the tests

```
private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k)
    {
        // Implement me!
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> table = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(table.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            table.put(arr[i], table.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            if (k <= table.get(arr[i])) {
                ans = Math.min(ans, arr[i]);
            }
        }else{
            table.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }

        return ans;
    }
```

Here is the empty code with all of the test cases:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab5
{

    /**
     *  Problem 1: Find the smallest integer that appears at least k times.
     */
    private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k)
    {
    // Implement me!
       return 0;
    }
    /**
     *  Problem 2: Find two distinct indices i and j such that A[i] = A[j] and |i - j| <= k.
     */
    private static int[] problem2(int[] arr, int k)
    {
        // Implement me!
        int i = -1;
        int j = -1;
        return new int[] { i, j };
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Do not change any of the code below!

    private static final int LabNo = 5;
    private static final String quarter = "Fall 2020";
    private static final Random rng = new Random(123456);

    private static boolean testProblem1(int[][] testCase)
    {
        int[] arr = testCase[0];
        int k = testCase[1][0];

        int answer = problem1(arr.clone(), k);

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i = j)
        {
            for (; j < arr.length && arr[i] == arr[j]; j++) { }

            if (j - i >= k)
            {
                return answer == arr[i];
            }
        }

        return false; // Will never happen.
    }

    private static boolean testProblem2(int[][] testCase)
    {
        int[] arr = testCase[0];
        int k = testCase[1][0];

        int[] answer = problem2(arr.clone(), k);

        if (answer == null || answer.length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Arrays.sort(answer);

        // Check answer
        int i = answer[0];
        int j = answer[1];
        return i != j
            && j - i <= k
            && i >= 0
            && j < arr.length
            && arr[i] == arr[j];
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("CS 302 -- " + quarter + " -- Lab " + LabNo);
        testProblems(1);
        testProblems(2);
    }

    private static void testProblems(int prob)
    {
        int noOfLines = prob == 1 ? 100000 : 500000;

        System.out.println("-- -- -- -- --");
        System.out.println(noOfLines + " test cases for problem " + prob + ".");

        boolean passedAll = true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfLines; i++)
        {

            int[][] testCase = null;

            boolean passed = false;
            boolean exce = false;

            try
            {
                switch (prob)
                {
                    case 1:
                        testCase = createProblem1(i);
                        passed = testProblem1(testCase);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        testCase = createProblem2(i);
                        passed = testProblem2(testCase);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                passed = false;
                exce = true;
            }

            if (!passed)
            {
                System.out.println("Test " + i + " failed!" + (exce ? " (Exception)" : ""));
                passedAll = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (passedAll)
        {
            System.out.println("All test passed.");
        }

    }

    private static int[][] createProblem1(int testNo)
    {
        int size = rng.nextInt(Math.min(1000, testNo)) + 5;

        int[] numbers = getRandomNumbers(size, size);
        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        int maxK = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i = j)
        {
            for (; j < size && numbers[i] == numbers[j]; j++) { }
            maxK = Math.max(maxK, j - i);
        }

        int k = rng.nextInt(maxK) + 1;

        shuffle(numbers);

        return new int[][] { numbers, new int[] { k } };
    }

    private static int[][] createProblem2(int testNo)
    {
        int size = rng.nextInt(Math.min(1000, testNo)) + 5;

        int[] numbers = getRandomNumbers(size, size);

        int i = rng.nextInt(size);
        int j = rng.nextInt(size - 1);
        if (i <= j) j++;

        numbers[i] = numbers[j];

        return new int[][] { numbers, new int[] { Math.abs(i - j) } };
    }

    private static void shuffle(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int rndInd = rng.nextInt(arr.length - i) + i;
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[rndInd];
            arr[rndInd] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static int[] getRandomNumbers(int range, int size)
    {
        int numbers[] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = rng.nextInt(2 * range) - range;
        }

        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did these changes however they still fail the test cases.

Comment: Haven't gone through detailed code but one mistake is `int ans = 0;` , i.e. you are using `Math.min` with it, so everytime minimum will be zero (if input will have positive integers only) . So instead of initializing it with 0, initialize with Maximum value available as input.

Comment: ah thank you for pointing that out @LUC1F3R The arrays in the test cases are all random so I won't know what the maximum would be, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Ok, if you are not sure of input limit then just use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is supported to be maximum value Integer can hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was able to pass all the cases! Thank you to everyone who helped!!

```
private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k)
    {
    // Implement me!
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> table = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(table.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                table.put(arr[i], table.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            }else{
                table.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }
         
        Set<Integer> keys = table.keySet();
        
        for(int i : keys){
            if(table.get(i) >= k){
               ans = Math.min(ans,i);
            }
        }
        
        if(ans != Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            return ans;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k) {
        // Implement me!
        Map<Integer, Integer> table = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (table.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                table.put(arr[i], table.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                table.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : table.entrySet()) { 
            //As treemap is sorted, we return the first key with value >=k.
            if(entry.getValue()>=k)
                return entry.getKey();
        }
        
        //Not found
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Hello! This does pass all of the test cases, but I unfortunately have to use HashMaps, not TreeMaps

Comment: You can use hashmap, but you will have to traverse entire map, to get the smallest key.

Comment: I will attempt this, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are a few mistakes. First, the line where you initialize `ans`,

```
int ans = 0;
```

You should initialize `ans` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so that when you find an integer that appears at least `k` times for the first time that `ans` gets set to that integer appropriately. Second, in your for loop, there's no reason to skip the first element while iterating the array so `i` should be initialized to `0` instead of `1`. Also, in that same line, you want to iterate through the entire array, and in your loop's condition right now you have `i < k` when `k` is not the length of the array. The length of the array is denoted by `arr.length` so the condition should instead be `i < arr.length`. Third, in this line,

```
if (k < table.get(arr[i])){
```

where you are trying to check if an integer has occurred at least `k` times in the array so far while iterating through the array, the `<` operator should be changed to `<=` since the keyword here is **at least k times**, not "more than `k` times". Fourth, `k` should never change so you can get rid of this line of code,

```
k = table.get(arr[i]);
```

After applying all of those changes, your function should look like this:

```
private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k)
{
    // Implement me!
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> table = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(table.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            table.put(arr[i], table.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            if (k <= table.get(arr[i])) {
                ans = Math.min(ans, arr[i]);
            }
        }else{
            table.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you!! This for some reason does not pass the test cases :/ I am going to add the test cases to the original post in case you would like to try some things out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @puyopop, could you try again? Just edited my answer because I forgot to change a `<` to `<=`, so I'm not sure if you used my latest answer.

Comment: Hi! I tried again and it passed one of the test cases, but not all of them. Thank you though!

Comment: @puyopop which test case failed? 1 or 2? because problem 2 seems to be completely unrelated

Comment: It was test 2 that failed

Comment: @puyopop in that case I believe my answer solves your question since you only asked about test case/problem 1. The 2nd test case/problem seems to be a completely different question that asks for a different solution. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ahh with how these work for each problem there are about 1000 test cases. So for problem one, the one we are working on, it failed on its 2nd case. Sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

- collect frequencies of each number in a `Map<Integer, Integer>` (number and its count)
- set least to a large value
- iterate over entries

  - ignore entry if its value is less than `k`
  - if entry key is less than current least, store it as least
- return least

One line implementation:

```
private static int problem1(int[] arr, int k) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() >= k)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .reduce(MAX_VALUE, Math::min);
}
```